# How can i extract an xml files from a txt file?

Tags: xml, text

I have a txt file in the below format

```
<Information>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <Name>Sam</Name>
   <State>Seattle</State>
   <Country>US</Country>
</Information>

<Information>
   <ID>2</ID>
   <Name>srikhar</Name>
   <State>Las Vegas</State>
   <Country>US</Country>
</Information>

<Information>
   <ID>3</ID>
   <Name>sima</Name>
   <State>Ilinois</State>
   <Country>US</Country>
</Information>
```

I want to separate the  data in `<Information> ...</Information>` to different XML FILES. Based on the above scenario i need to get 3 XML files.

Is there any way how can achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Any scripting language that can work with text files, like VBScript, Powershell. Is this on windows?

Comment: Yeah it is windows

Answer (score -1):

Tried it last time but I learned too dangerous to approach it that way. The outputs you get are very much "NOT PRECISE"  As I see the contents, seems to be a valid xml structure so my recommendation is to use **tinyxml** to extract . You may need to rename the file to change the extension to .xml.

Comment: So you are saying to change the .txt file extension to .xml and the use the tinyxml to extract the inside xml files right ?

Comment: now I am working with xml files, and tried reading .txt file using tinyxml2, so far, outputs are just the same with files with .xml extension. The correctness of your xml structure is far more important than the extension, after all, .xml is also just an text file.

Answer (score -1):

You xml is not well formed so you have to use XmlReader with settings equal to Fragment.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "Information")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("Information");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement information = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    string id = (string)information.Element("ID");
                    string filename = string.Format(@"c:\temp\informaton{0}.xml", id);
                    information.Save(filename);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are using XMLReader class in c# to extract xml from my .txt file right ? For using the above code do i need to install any tool like XML viewer etc.

Comment: Correct.  Uses Net Library XML and Linq XML.  Input/output files can have any extension.  I used xml, but you can use .txt